# Web Scraping tables from an HTML file

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

Hello all I am hoping to get some help with taking the tables in my HTML file and importing them into a csv file. I am very very new to web scraping so for give me if I am completely wrong with my code. The HTML file holds three separate table I am trying to extract; estimate, sampling error, and number of non-zero plots in estimate.

My code is shown below:

```
#import necessary libraries
import urllib2
import pandas as pd

#specify URL
table = "file:///C:/Users/TMccw/Anaconda2/FiaAPI/outFArea18.html"

#Query the website & return the html to the variable 'page'
page = urllib2.urlopen(table)

#import the bs4 functions to parse the data returned from the website
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Parse the html in the 'page' variable & store it in bs4 format
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

#Print out the html code with the function prettify
print soup.prettify()

#Find the tables & check type
table2 = soup.find_all('table')
print(table2)
print type(table2)

#Create new table as a dataframe
new_table = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(0,4))

#Extract the info from the HTML code 
soup.find('table').find_all('td'),{'align':'right'}

#Remove the tags and extract table info into CSV
???
```

Here is the HTML for the first table "Estimate":

```
 ` Estimate:
     </b>
     </caption>
     <tr>
     <td>
     </td>
    <td align="center" colspan="5">
     <b>
      Ownership group
     </b>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th>
     <b>
      Forest type group
     </b>
    </th>
    <td>
     <b>
      Total
     </b>
    </td>
    <td>
     <b>
      National Forest
     </b>
    </td>
    <td>
     <b>
      Other federal
     </b>
    </td>
    <td>
     <b>
      State and local
     </b>
    </td>
    <td>
     <b>
      Private
     </b>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td nowrap="">
     <b>
      Total
     </b>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     4,875,993
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     195,438
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     169,500
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     392,030
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     4,119,025
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td nowrap="">
     <b>
      White / red / jack pine group
     </b>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     40,492
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     3,426
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     -
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     10,850
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     26,217
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td nowrap="">
     <b>
      Loblolly / shortleaf pine group
     </b>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     38,267
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     11,262
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     997
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     4,015
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     21,993
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td nowrap="">
     <b>
      Other eastern softwoods group
     </b>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     25,181
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     -
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     -
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     -
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     25,181
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td nowrap="">
     <b>
      Exotic softwoods group
     </b>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     5,868
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     -
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     -
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     662
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     5,206
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td nowrap="">
     <b>
      Oak / pine group
     </b>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     144,238
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     9,592
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     -
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     21,475
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     113,171
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td nowrap="">
     <b>
      Oak / hickory group
     </b>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     3,480,272
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     152,598
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     123,900
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     285,305
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     2,918,470
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td nowrap="">
     <b>
      Oak / gum / cypress group
     </b>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     76,302
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     -
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     12,209
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     9,311
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     54,782
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td nowrap="">
     <b>
      Elm / ash / cottonwood group
     </b>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     652,001
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     7,105
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     25,431
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     46,096
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     573,369
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td nowrap="">
     <b>
      Maple / beech / birch group
     </b>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     346,718
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     10,871
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     818
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     12,748
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     322,281
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td nowrap="">
     <b>
      Other hardwoods group
     </b>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     21,238
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     585
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     -
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     -
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     20,653
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td nowrap="">
     <b>
      Exotic hardwoods group
     </b>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     2,441
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     -
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     -
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     -
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     2,441
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td nowrap="">
     <b>
      Nonstocked
     </b>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     42,975
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     -
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     6,144
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     1,570
    </td>
    <td align="right">
     35,261
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <br/>
  <table border="4" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
   <caption>
    <b>`
```

Comment: Why would you open a local file with `urllib2` ?

Comment: I am not too sure actually. What would you use instead? Like I said i'm very new to web scraping

Comment: There's nothing actually wrong with doing that. It's just unnecessary since you can open a local file and obtain its contents by reading it to make it available for BeautifulSoup.

Comment: If the HTML is too large to include in the question then would you post it somewhere so that we can take a look at it?

Comment: Just added the HTML for the first table I want to extract the info from

Comment: I should have mentioned that if you want to reply to someone (like me!) you should enter an 'at' symbol which will prompt this system to give you a menu of people to whom you can direct your message.

Comment: Thanks @BillBell I didn't know I could do that! I'm new to the stack over flow community!

Comment: You're very welcome. Good to have you aboard.

Answer (score 1):

I made four tables almost identical to yours and put them into a fairly respectable page of HTML. Then I ran this code.

```
>>> import bs4
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(open('temp.htm').read(), 'html.parser')
>>> tables = soup.findAll('table')
>>> for t, table in enumerate(tables):
...     df = pd.read_html(str(table), skiprows=2)
...     df[0].to_csv('table%s.csv' % t)
```

The results were four files like this, named table0.csv through table3.csv.

```
,0,1,2,3,4,5
0,Total,4875993,195438,169500,392030,4119025
1,White / red / jack pine group,40492,3426,-,10850,26217
2,Loblolly / shortleaf pine group,38267,11262,997,4015,21993
3,Other eastern softwoods group,25181,-,-,-,25181
4,Exotic softwoods group,5868,-,-,662,5206
5,Oak / pine group,144238,9592,-,21475,113171
6,Oak / hickory group,3480272,152598,123900,285305,2918470
7,Oak / gum / cypress group,76302,-,12209,9311,54782
8,Elm / ash / cottonwood group,652001,7105,25431,46096,573369
9,Maple / beech / birch group,346718,10871,818,12748,322281
10,Other hardwoods group,21238,585,-,-,20653
11,Exotic hardwoods group,2441,-,-,-,2441
12,Nonstocked,42975,-,6144,1570,35261
```

Perhaps the main thing I should mention is that I skipped the same number of rows in each table that BeautifulSoup delivered. If the number of header lines in the tables varies then you will have to do something more clever or just discard lines in the output files and omit the `skiprows` parameter.

Comment: Thanks @BillBell, I tried running the code you provided. Everything is all and well up till line 7. Here's my code

Comment: `import bs4
import pandas as pd
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(open('outFArea18.html').read(), 'html.parser')
tables = soup.findAll('table')
for t, table in enumerate(tables):
    df = pd.read_html(str(table), skiprows=2)
    df[0].to_csv('table%s.csv' % t)`  I get an IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: I assume that `df` is empty. Which implied that `BeautifulSoup` found no tables. You should check the length of `tables`. If it's zero then look at the html file to verify that it actually contains tables.

Comment: IIRC, I had to add a `<table>` to the beginning of your file to make my test file.

Comment: I am able to run the code before the for loop: `import bs4
import pandas as pd
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(open('outFArea18.html').read(), 'html.parser')
tables = soup.findAll('table')
print(tables)`

Comment: that code gives me the tables I want. What do you mean by "check the length of `tables` ?

Comment: The line of code `tables = soup.findAll('table')` puts a list in `tables` which can have zero length. I often check the length of this list if only to learn whether the attempt to find tables has failed completely, which leads to a zero-length list. I use, simply, `len(tables)`.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure as to what the exact question is here but right off the bat I can see an error that will throw you off a bit.

```
new_table = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(0-4))
```

Needs to be

```
new_table = pd.DataFrame(columns=range(0,4))
```

The result of range(0-4) is actually range(-4) which evaluates to range(0,-4) whereas you want range(0,4).  You can just pass range(4) as the parameter or range(0,4).

Comment: Sorry if my question is unclear. The main question is what I am doing wrong? Ok got it, thanks!!

Comment: gotcha, I believe that should fix it but I am not  very experienced with beautifulsoup.

Comment: Use `soup.find('table').find_all('td' {'align':'right')` to get the values.

Comment: Thanks @t.m.adam. I used what you wrote above but it gave me a syntax error. I re-wrote your code as `soup.find('table').find_all('td'),{'align':'right'}` . So this gave me all the information in the three tables I want to extract from. However, the tags are still there. I am guessing all I need to do now is remove the tags and put the info into an csv file?

Comment: Use this list `[td.text for td in soup.find('table').find_all('td', {'align':'right')]`

Comment: forgot a }, should be [td.text for td in soup.find('table').find_all('td', {'align':'right'})]